# Fiddler: Define Request Type to match in Auto responder as in POST or GET?

Tags: fiddler

I want to match url: `m.test.com/findServer`, but only when POST request is made.

After Googling i found that I need to put `METHOD: POST`. But having zero experience with Fiddler I am not able to figure out where to put this in URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Request URL Pattern` box (the top edit box in the `Rule Editor` box at the bottom of the AutoResponder tab), enter

`METHOD:POST m.test.com/findServer`

Comment: Thank you. Is it just me, or is the help page provided by Fiddler itself for filters, really useless? I couldn't even get what the help page was trying to tell me.